# What is the SKSpriteNode equivalent on Android?

Tags: android

I'm making a game on Android, and I need to do it native. I'm working with FrameLayout, because I can put the elements in a coordinate system and I can place children of the same FrameLayout type with images or shapes.

But the doubt is, there is some equivalent in Android to make games as it is in Swift the SpriteKit.